# Json files losing indentation when using Beautify extension

Tags: json, indentation

I have a JSON file that when I save on it using Beautify extension loses its format (indentation).
I use VS code editor.
If I disable Beautify, it works well and the indentation remains. Any suggestions on how to configure this are welcome.
All other files work well and are well indented when using Beautify.
Regards,
Alek

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the beautify settings in the settings.json file.
For settings reference follow this link: https://github.com/HookyQR/VSCodeBeautify/blob/master/Settings.md

You can open the settings.json from the beautify extension page clicking on the settings button.

You can also try to use another extension called *Prettier*, it works like a charm for me!

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I have tried prettier before beautify, but for some reason, it doesn't work. When I click save, is not formatting properly. I have checked settings, prettier was my default formatter, yet nothing happens when I save. When I check it,  it says: "Invalid prettier configuration file detected. See log for details. ". Thank you for the file, I will keep digging on the settings for the beautify extension.